# Auto quotes around string in c# - build in method?

Tags: c#, string

Is there some build in method that add quotes around string in c# ?

Comment: Could you clarify your question a little bit!

Comment: from string abc I want to make string "abc" and I wonder whether there is some build in method in some class that can do the job. I know it is 5 line of code to write your own.

Comment: @Darger: And what if the string contains a quote? What will you use it for?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Do you mean *just* adding quotes? Like this?

```
text = "\"" + text + "\"";
```

? I don't know of a built-in method to do that, but it would be easy to write one if you wanted to:

```
public static string SurroundWithDoubleQuotes(this string text)
{
    return SurroundWith(text, "\"");
}

public static string SurroundWith(this string text, string ends)
{
    return ends + text + ends;
}
```

That way it's a little more general:

```
text = text.SurroundWithDoubleQuotes();
```

or

```
text = text.SurroundWith("'"); // For single quotes
```

I can't say I've needed to do this often enough to make it worth having a method though...

Comment: you're slipping. `this text` should be `this string text` :)

Comment: Easy to write, but you have to write it a billion times unless you make your own library or something. Or bring in a third party lib for something this trivial. Would be awfully handy if it was just in the standard lib.

Comment: @jpmc26: I can't say I have to do it very often... Partly as if I'm quoting, it's usually to write JSON or something similar, in which case I'd be using a library anyway.

Comment: I find I use it fairly frequently when building up logging messages, especially with a list of things. (E.g., `String.Join(", ", someValues.Select(v => "\"" + v + "\"")` and then passing *that* into a `Format` call.) It comes up in PowerShell, too, when trying to pass things to an executable a certain way. (SQL*Plus is quite finicky about when the quote marks go.)

Comment: @jpmc26: Well in C# I'd use interpolated string literals making it much simpler - and I'd probably use single quotes to avoid having to escape anything.  But if you do decide to write a helper method, it would only be once per application. Either way it doesn't feel like a big deal to me. For SQL I wouldn't be building value into the SQL at all, but using parameterized SQL wherever possible.

Comment: SQL*Plus is Oracle's command line tool, so I'm talking about command lines, not SQL statements. ;)

Comment: @jpmc26: Right, but my point is that that's an edge case, not something you do "a billion times". You may well want to write a library to make it easier to start processes, and that would have more than just quoting in.

Answer (score 12):

```
string quotedString = string.Format("\"{0}\"", originalString);
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, using concatenation and escaped characters

```
myString = "\"" + myString + "\"";
```

Maybe an extension method

```
public static string Quoted(this string str)
{
    return "\"" + str + "\"";
}
```

Usage:

```
var s = "Hello World"
Console.WriteLine(s.Quoted())
```

Answer (score 5):

No but you can write your own or create an extension method

```
string AddQuotes(string str)
{
    return string.Format("\"{0}\"", str);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using Escape Characters**

Just prefix the special character with a backslash, which is known as an `escape character`.

**Simple Examples**

```
string MyString = "Hello";
Response.Write(MyString);
```

This would print:

```
Hello
```

But:

```
string MyString = "The man said \"Hello\"";
Response.Write(MyString);
```

Would print:

```
The man said "Hello"
```

**Alternative**

You can use the useful `@` operator to help escape strings, see this link:

http://www.kowitz.net/archive/2007/03/06/the-c-string-literal

Then, for quotes, you would use double quotes to represent a single quote.  For example:

```
string MyString = @"The man said ""Hello"" and went on his way";
Response.Write(MyString);
```

Outputs:

```
The man said "Hello" and went on his way
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit C# of a novice myself, so have at me, but I have this in a catch-all utility class 'cause I miss Perl:

```
// overloaded quote - if no quote chars spec'd, use ""
public static string quote(string s) {
    return quote(s, "\"\"");
}

// quote a string
// q = two quote chars, like "", '', [], (), {} ...
//     or another quoted string (quote-me-like-that)
public static string quote(string s, string q) {

    if(q.Length == 0)        // no quote chars, use ""
        q = "\"\"";
    else if(q.Length == 1)    // one quote char, double it - your mileage may vary
        q = q + q;
    else if(q.Length > 2)    // longer string == quote-me-like-that
        q = q.Substring(0, 1) + q.Substring(q.Length - 1, 1);

    if(s.Length == 0)    // nothing to quote, return empty quotes
        return q;

    return q[0] + s + q[1];

}
```

Use it like this:

```
quote("this with default");
quote("not recommended to use one char", "/");
quote("in square brackets", "[]");
quote("quote me like that", "{like this?}");
```

Returns:

```
"this with default"
/not recommended to use one char/
[in square brackets]
{quote me like that}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I wanted to add quotes only if the string was not already surrounded in quotes, so I did:

(this is slightly different to what I actually did, so it's untested)

```
public static string SurroundWith(this string text, string ends)
{
    if (!(text.StartsWith(ends) && text.EndsWith(ends)))
    {
        return string.Format("{1}{0}{1}", text, ends);
    }
    else
    {
        return text;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modern `C#` version below. Using [string.Create()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.create?view=net-6.0) we avoid unnecessary allocations:

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Quote(this string s) => Surround(s, '"');

    public static string Surround(this string s, char c)
    {
        return string.Create(s.Length + 2, s, (chars, state) =>
        {
            chars[0] = c;
            state.CopyTo(chars.Slice(1));
            chars[^1] = c;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such built in method to do your requirement

There is SplitQuotes method that does something
Input - This is a "very long" string
Output - This, is, a, very long, string

When you get a string from textbox or some control it comes with quotes.

If still you want to place quotes then you can use this kind of method

```
private string PlaceQuotes(string str, int startPosition, int lastPosition)
{
    string quotedString = string.Empty;
    string replacedString = str.Replace(str.Substring(0, startPosition),str.Substring(0, startPosition).Insert(startPosition, "'")).Substring(0, lastPosition).Insert(lastPosition, "'");
    return String.Concat(replacedString, str.Remove(0, replacedString.Length));
}
```